# SQL Server float column is removing .00

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

We have a client database that is using a float datatype for a column.  If I insert 55.01 into it it's fine, but if the value inserted is 55.00 it removes the .00.  Does anyone know how I can prevent it from doing this?  Ideally they don't want the database altered.  Is there anything I can do to this query to fix it?

```
Insert into print_receipt (box_number) values (55.00)
```

Comment: Sounds more like a display issue rather than a database issue.

Comment: I agree, the value of 55.00 and 55 is the same

Comment: Please note that for floating-point, certain values are **NOT** accurately representable (for example, `.1`).  This is why you _never_ store 'money' amounts in float/double fields (use decimal or int instead), although that doesn't appear to be the issue here.  However, this can still become an issue, if you attempt to use values to far outside of the 'accurate' range; if the input number isn't accurately representable, it'll be modified to be a representable value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you all you want is a trailing `00`, there's no need to change the database since it's already accurate.

Change your presentation layer, or just add a cast to your `SELECT`s:

`select CAST(CAST(55.00 as float) as decimal (10,2))`

Comment: It's an example since his data is already a float. It's a runnable sample instead of `SELECT CAST(yourfloatfield as decimal(10,2))`

Comment: Thanks, I changed it via the presentation layer to make it work.  Just seems really odd that sql server removes the .00 on a float field.  Since it's not our database and we aren't allowed to change it, I can't simply make the column a varchar/text field.

Comment: @Nathan - bear in mind that behind the scenes, `float` is a multiplication like `5*10^1` - it makes sense it would display this with the least number if significant digits possible.

Comment: You need to switch to storing decimals if the decimal places are significant to you. They will NEVER be stored if you use float. This answer will just let you always display two decimal places, not the amount that was actually saved.